# Is there a way to specific the block when buy BEP20 token?

Tags: web3js, nodejs, bsc

To avoid bot, some of fairlaunch and dev make a 99% tax in 2 first block buying after liquidity, it called antibot system.
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x097f4662292954a5373e7d4c513a1f00559563ad5a5fd2616fc22ebae491f4ba say like this, add LP in block 10509733, how we can buy in 10509735 block?

Answer (score 0):

You can check block number in web3 with this code:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
```

and check it in a specific period. If it is equal to 10509735, then do something. But you have to pay more gas then average to get in that block.